# VBA autofiltering for name

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting an error when I am running my selection.autofilter code and cannot figure out the problem.

I am trying to autofilter by name 'JHILL2' in column F of a spreadsheet

```
Sub filter_jhill2()

Set ws = Worksheets("modified_report")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("modified_report").Select

Selection.AutoFilter
    Worksheets("modified_report").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="JHILL2"

End Sub
```

I am trying to have just the rows with JHILL2 be returned

Comment: Normally you don't need to `Select`. You don't need the `Sheets("modified_report").Select` and `Selection.AutoFilter`.